# Newbie CSS needs help debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, debugging

This is my first post to Stack, I'm having trouble debugging some CSS errors on a project I am working on. Here is a link to the page:

http://musiccomputing.com/copy-of-studioblade-5-61-key-macos-x/

You can see how the thumbnails seem to repeat, and there is some text jumbling on the right side, this is what it should look like: musiccomputing.com/studioblade-5-61-key-macos-x/ (sorry they wouldn't let me post more than 2 links).

I was working on adding a "tabbed" section under the product description. Here is the code I added which caused the aforementioned issues to occur. http://pastebin.com/JhbbmFTb. I have been trying to debug this with Pesticide and Firebug, but unfortunately I am still learning, so decided to turn to you guys who I know could solve this fairly quickly.

(by the way this is on a Bigcommerce platform)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When posting questions to stack - try to isolate your issue as much as you can. This makes it far quicker for people to debug your code and provide a good answer. The best way to do this is to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). This is the accepted method for sharing code as opposed to pastebin. You should almost always do this as opposed to providing a direct link to your site.

Answer (score 1):

On your working version - your select boxes are wrapped in a div with a class of selector. This class on the parent is assigning the following CSS to the select box which fixes the styling issues:

```
    div.selector select {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        -moz-opacity: 0;
        border: none;
        background: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Add the parent back - or add a new parent with a class of .select and the boxes will display correctly again.

**Edit**

On your thumbnail viewer there is a class of "ProductTinyImageList" with some styles that are being added dynamically - probably via JavaScript.

When looking in the console on your site there is also an error on line 12 of init.js - this error is probably what is preventing the rest of your JS from executing and probably what is breaking your thumbnail viewer.

The first thing I would do is fix that JS error - then retest.

Comment: Thanks James, I would have went with Jfiddle or Codepen, but I didnt all the weird variables Bigcommerce uses would show up properly. doh!!! I was reading your answer, so you're saying the issue is with the ProductTinyImageList and not something with the additional added code?

Comment: @EdRhone Those are the two parts of your HTML which are different. But  I believe it's probably because your JavaScript is returning an error on the broken page. If you go to the broken page and open your dev tools (F12) and then choose the console tab - you will see a JavaScript error on the page. If you can fix that error - your problems will more than likely go away.